# GNUPlot: Auto-plot all columns from standard in without extra logic/semantic noise

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have the following file:

```
0 a b c
1 1 2 2
2 4 4 2
3 8 6 2
```

And I want to send it from the command line:

```
cat foofile | gnuplot -e 'file="/dev/stdin"' plot.p
```

With the following plotfile:

```
set key outside
plot for [col=2:4] file using 0:col with lines title columnheader
```

Now, suppose I would like to send GNUPlot an **arbitrary** columnar file with anywhere from 1:N columns, where N is arbitrary.

Since I am opening a pipe from within GNUPlot, it seems that I will not be able to read from it to determine the number of columns.  How do I tell GNUPlot (in a clean way) to simply plot each column until there are none left to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  plot for [col=2:*] file using 0:col with lines title columnheader
```

However, if you know what the file name is in order to issue the "cat" command you would do better to just pass the filename to gnuplot rather than using a pipe.

```
  gnuplot -e 'file="foofile"' plot.p
```

Alternatively, you can feed the input via channels other than /dev/stdin.  Here is an excerpt from the documentation section for `piped-data`:

```
 On systems with an fdopen() function, data can be read from an arbitrary file
 descriptor attached to either a file or pipe.  To read from file descriptor
 `n` use `'<&n'`.  This allows you to easily pipe in several data files in a
 single call from a POSIX shell:

       $ gnuplot -p -e "plot '<&3', '<&4'" 3<data-3 4<data-4
       $ ./gnuplot 5< <(myprogram -with -options)
       gnuplot> plot '<&5'
```

Comment: this is a very tiny, minimal, and verifiable example of what amounts to a very large set of plots from a very large cube of data -- a dataset I would not like to write to disk for every plot. I think I ran into your answer earlier, and I still have to write to and read from disk to accomplish this.  I think the answer may involve somehow reading the standard input into memory within gnuplot.  Otherwise, I probably have to go to python and matplotlib.

Comment: You are not limited to reading data from stdin.  You can have any number of input channels open and plot from the data they provide.  The details are necessarily shell- and OS- dependent but see the examples provided in `help piped-data`. Extract from the docs added to previous answer.